# How can I deal with excess seeds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I reduce the amount of space my seeds take up without losing them? They can't be put into a solid block like ores and wheat. Any ideas?

Comment: why would you want enough seeds that your having trouble storing them in the first place? and the answer to your question otherwise, is you cant

Comment: A single chest holds 1728 seeds in a 1x1x1 area. I don't know if you can get more compact than that.

Comment: Note this may not be 100% intuitive - you can simply discard any unneeded items by moving them to the "world" outside the inventory window from the inventory. Just leave them lying and they vanish in 5 minutes. Since wheat farming always produces more seed than it uses, simply discard most of the surplus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seeds cannot be compacted down in any way like wheat or ores are able to.

If you really need to store that many seeds, a single chest only takes two wood logs to craft; they are relatively inexpensive, so as long as you have the physical space, you can fit a very large amount of seeds into as many double chests as you need.

If space **is** an issue, there are also designs which allow you to pack a massive amount of storage into a small area:

Answer (score 3):

You can make a composter using seven wooden half slabs.  Put the seeds in the composter and it will give you bone meal.  You can also start another farm for extra seeds and extra bonemeal :)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use them up, you could feed baby chickens to make them grow faster and then kill them for some chicken. About 1 full stack of seeds can make a chicken grow in about 15 seconds from the start of feeding it to when the chicken is fully grown

Answer (score 1):

With recent development, I would recommend now that they be [composted](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Composter) into bone meal.

Answer (score 0):

Double chest with Hopper connected on top. Place composter on top of the Hopper. Add additional Hopper feeding into the composter. Add double chest on top of that Hopper. Stick all your unwanted seeds, sugar cane, etc in there and just watch the bonemeal add up. Took 2 minutes to make and 3 minutes to come up with. I forgot to mention... Do NOT feed the composter from the side, only the top worked for me, and to be honest that is the only thing that would make sense anyway lol.